# How to show withdraw payment amount in MetaMask?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, openzeppelin

I'm using [OpenZeppelin's PullPayment](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/payment#PullPayment) to handle payouts from my eth smart contracts. While withdrawing the coins with MetaMask, MetaMask shows 0 ETH when withdrawing for instance 2 ETH:
[image: MetaMask Notification when withdrawing payments]

Is it possible for the payout amount to appear in MetaMask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, due to the design of MetaMask. There are a couple of ERCs to show human-readable transaction data fields, but as far as I know none of them have been adopted yet.